# extract email adress from csv file

Tags: linux, shell

I want to extract all email address from csv file.
how to do this action.
by the way the location of the email is not organized by column or by row.

in fact there is no regular format, but I give you an example

```
 "bla bla bla bla Website: www.mysite.com ; Email: information@email.com";usa;
```

so the question is how to extract the email address from this sentence ?

Comment: i don't get it, csv files tend to have "columns" ... Care to give some sample data?

Comment: So you want to extract all strings from a file, where the strings are valid email addresses? Please provide an example

Comment: hard to give advice without seeing some sample input files.

Comment: So the input file format is irrelevant, you just want to harvest every email address in it...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

thank for all;
I found the correct answer for my question, it is :

```
grep -E -o "\b[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\b" file.csv | sort -u > email_list
```

Comment: "sort -u" : used to avoid write duplicated email in the email_list file 
    "> email_list" : displayed result will be written to email_list text file

Answer (score 3):

Please adjust the regular expression if needed (`\S+@\S+` probably too simple):

```
grep -o -P '\S+@\S+' input.csv
```

From `man grep`:

```
-o, --only-matching
      Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, 
      with each such part on a separate output line.
-P, --perl-regexp
      Interpret PATTERN as a Perl regular expression (PCRE, see below).  
      This is highly experimental and grep -P may warn of unimplemented features.
```

To sort and skip duplicates:

```
grep -o -P '\S+@\S+' input.csv | sort -u
```

Answer (score 0):

extract email adsress  from folder full of csv file; just using perl

```
cat *.csv > all.csv 
perl -wne'while(/[\w\.\-]+@[\w\.\-]+\w+/g){print "$&\n"}' all.csv | sort -u > output.txt
```